# HTML / CSS - how to have one background image for entire table

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-image

EDIT: okay turns out it was browser issues. Hopefully someone can close this before I get even more negative votes -.-

I want a dark colored image as the background of my table, with the font and border lines to be a light color, say white. Here is my HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
         <td>blank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
         <td>blank</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here is  my CSS

```
table {
    background:url(../images/bgimage.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    width:180px; 
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:180px; 
    height:200px;   
    }
```

however, this is not working and it is not placing any image onto the screen. How come? I even tried placing !important at the end, like so

```
background:url(../images/15387_isopropyl_alcohol.jpg) !important;
```

but I still got nothnig Is it supposed to work? If it is, then I guess I will ahve to go through my entire code again and see if anything is wrong.. Is there another way to place a background image behind the table? I was thinking putting the table in a div and then giving the div a background image and then making the position absolute but that didn't work either, the image didn't even show up for some reason again.

Comment: Wrong path to the image? Other CSS interfering?

Comment: It works for me, problably you have a wrong path on your background url. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfB9n/)

Comment: Check your browser's inspector and see what's going on (could be a specificity issue or incorrect path).

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your table inside a `<div>` and set the background on the `<div>` instead.

**UPDATE:**

The `div` suggestion was just to get a quick fix but it all depends on whether your image reference is even working and also what your trying to do and why you are even using an background image in the first place.

You end up having to force a table to be the same size as the image or repeat the image (which may or may not be what you want) or use `background-size: contain;` to scale the image to fit inside the `<div>` or use `background-size: cover;` to scale the image to the size of the `<div>`, these last 2 only works in more modern browsers.

This fiddle example fixes the table to within the width and height you specified. You can still apply the background image to the table, this is an example of doing it with a wrapping `<div>` so you could also put other elements infront of the background if necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/wbPpa/6/

html:

```
<div class="theme">
<table class="theme-table">
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
         <td>blank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
         <td>blank</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

css:

```
.theme-table, .theme {
    height: 200px;
    width: 180px;  
}

.theme-table {
    border:1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;

}

.theme {
    background:url(http://placehold.it/180x200);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is an indirect answer, but still a solution to the problem (also was my first thought) +1

Comment: Why would this matter?

Comment: When I did that,t he image appeared beside the table. I then made the images position be absolute, then the table covered the entire image. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The image is probably working, but hiding behind the table.  Try setting td opacity to 0.9 to see if the background image then displays.

```
td {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in the html element, you can use

```
style="background-image: url(http://yuordomain.com/background.jpg);"
```